# Watson Discovery Aggregation on Java API

Tags: java, watson, watson-discovery

Is there a way to use aggregations on Watson Discovery API for Java? In every test that I tried I receive stackoverflowerror.

EDIT:
Thats my aggregation:

```
nested(enriched_text.relations)
.filter(enriched_text.relations.type::incluiCultura)
.filter(enriched_text.relations.arguments.entities.text::"Orbit")
.term(enriched_text.relations.arguments.entities.text)
.term(enriched_text.relations.arguments)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official library had a problem with certains types of aggregation:
https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/issues/854

It seems that the bug was solved and the code merged in the last release (5.3.0): https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/releases